# OAuth1.0 header in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, oauth, axios

I've been using an [API](https://developers.liveperson.com/data-access-api-methods-agent-activity.html) via postman that uses OAuth1.0, successfully.
Now I'm building an API that calls this API but I'm having trouble when trying to set up the equivalent in javascript of the OAuth1.0.
The header looks like this:

```
'Authorization': 'OAuth oauth_consumer_key="XXX",oauth_token="XXX",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_timestamp="1559312415",oauth_nonce="XXX",oauth_version="1.0",oauth_signature="XXX"'
```

My problem is related to **oauth_nonce** and **oauth_signature**.
What are the hash function that I can use to generate those 2 parameters. 
Also, I'm using [AXIOS](https://github.com/axios/axios) for the request. 
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I was able to figure out a solution with Axios. I created an OauthHelper class to generate the `Authorization` header:

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
const oauth1a = require('oauth-1.0a');

const CONSUMERKEY = '<consumerKey>';
const CONSUMERSECRET = '<consumerSecret>';
const TOKENKEY = '<tokenKey>';
const TOKENSECRET = '<tokenSecret>';

class Oauth1Helper {
    static getAuthHeaderForRequest(request) {
        const oauth = oauth1a({
            consumer: { key: CONSUMERKEY, secret: CONSUMERSECRET },
            signature_method: 'HMAC-SHA1',
            hash_function(base_string, key) {
                return crypto
                    .createHmac('sha1', key)
                    .update(base_string)
                    .digest('base64')
            },
        })

        const authorization = oauth.authorize(request, {
            key: TOKENKEY,
            secret: TOKENSECRET,
        });

        return oauth.toHeader(authorization);
    }
}

module.exports = Oauth1Helper;
```

Then I was just able to make the post from wherever I need via Axios:

```
const request = {
    url: 'https://api-domain.com',
    method: 'POST',
    body: {
        "uniqueId": 1234
    }
};

const authHeader = Oauth1Helper.getAuthHeaderForRequest(request);

return await axios.post(
    request.url,
    request.body,
    { headers: authHeader });
```

Comment: Is it the same for get request .?

Comment: It should be, although I didn't explicitly test it out.

Comment: can you make a look at my question please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61458960/nodejs-unable-to-send-oauth-v1-params-in-get-request-with-axios

Comment: I am getting an error with this code. `TypeError: Cannot read property 'createHmac' of undefined`. Could you please help update this if possible ?

Is this signed with RSA-SHA1 signature

Comment: @GregVanGorp its been 5 hours since I'm banging my head with this. you are a life saver, wish I could upvote this 100 times, thanks a TON!

Comment: How to parse query params in that code? @GregVanGorp

Answer (score 3):

Here's one that doesn't need a package.

You'll need `makeHeader(consumer, token, request)` which works for me with Node's `https.request` but should also work for Axios.

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
const { stringify: qStringify } = require('querystring');
const { httpOptions, fetch } = require('./fetch');

function nonce() {
  return crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('hex');
}

function sign(baseStr, key) {
  return crypto.createHmac('sha1', key).update(baseStr).digest('base64');
}

function percentEncode(str) {
  const notEscapedRe = /[!'()*]/g;
  return encodeURIComponent(str).replace(notEscapedRe, (c) => `%${c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)}`);
}

function makeObjStr(parameters, quote = '"', split = ',') {
  const ordered = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(parameters).sort());
  return Object.entries(ordered).map(([key, value]) => `${percentEncode(key)}=${quote}${percentEncode(value)}${quote}`).join(split);
}

function authHeader(parameters) {
  return { Authorization: `OAuth ${makeObjStr(parameters)}` };
}

function makeHeader(consumer, token, request) {
  const oauthData = {
    oauth_consumer_key: consumer.key,
    oauth_token: token.key,
    oauth_nonce: nonce(),
    oauth_signature_method: 'HMAC-SHA1',
    oauth_timestamp: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000),
    oauth_version: '1.0',
  };
  const baseStr = [
    request.method.toUpperCase(),
    percentEncode(request.url),
    percentEncode(makeObjStr({ ...request.data, ...oauthData }, '', '&')),
  ].join('&');
  const signingKey = [percentEncode(consumer.secret), percentEncode(token.secret)].join('&');
  return authHeader({
    ...oauthData,
    oauth_signature: sign(baseStr, signingKey),
  });
}

function oAuth1Fetch({
  consumer, token, hostname, path, query = {},
}) {
  const request = {
    method: 'GET',
    url: `https://${hostname}${path}`,
    data: query,
  };
  return fetch({
    ...httpOptions,
    headers: makeHeader(consumer, token, request),
    hostname,
    path: `${path}?${qStringify(query)}`,
  });
}

module.exports = {
  oAuth1Fetch,
};
```

Here's my `fetch`:

```
const { Agent, request } = require('https');

const httpOptions = {
  agent: new Agent({ keepAlive: true }),
  'User-Agent': `AWS Lambda Node/${process.version} surflog.app`,
  // Accept: 'application/json',
};

function fetch(options) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const req = request(options, (res) => {
      const data = [];
      res.on('data', (chunk) => data.push(chunk));
      res.on('end', () => {
        const result = Buffer.concat(data).toString();
        console.log(res.statusCode);
        if (res.statusCode >= 200 && res.statusCode < 300) {
          resolve(result);
        } else {
          reject(result);
        }
      });
    });
    req.setTimeout(6000, (err) => {
      console.warn(err);
      console.warn('Timeout', options.hostname);
    });
    req.on('error', reject);
    req.end();
  });
}

module.exports = {
  httpOptions,
  fetch,
};
```

An example:

```
oAuth1Fetch({
  consumer: {
    key: 'xyz',
    secret: 'xyz',
  },
  token: {
    key: 'xyz',
    secret: 'xyz',
  },
  hostname: 'apis.garmin.com',
  path: '/wellness-api/rest/backfill/activities',
  query: {
    summaryStartTimeInSeconds: 1609459200,
    summaryEndTimeInSeconds: 1609459200 + 7776000,
  },
}).then(console.log).catch(console.error);
```

Answer (score -1):

This is an update to the solution that Greg Van Gorp raised earlier, but uses Crypto-JS. Since crypto is deprecated.

```
const crypto = require('crypto-js');
const oauth1a = require('oauth-1.0a');

const CONSUMERKEY = '<consumerKey>';
const CONSUMERSECRET = '<consumerSecret>';

class Oauth1Helper {
  static getAuthHeaderForRequest(request) {
    const oauth = oauth1a({
      consumer: {key: CONSUMERKEY, secret: CONSUMERSECRET},
      signature_method: 'HMAC-SHA1',
      hash_function(base_string, key) {
        return crypto.algo.HMAC
          .create(crypto.algo.SHA1, key)
          .update(base_string)
          .finalize()
          .toString(crypto.enc.Base64);
      },
    });

    const authorization = oauth.authorize(request);

    return oauth.toHeader(authorization);
  }
}

module.exports = Oauth1Helper;
```

I propose the solution a little differently since the API that it consumed did not require Tokens, but I understand that just passing the Tokens should work without problems, these are optional in the oauth1a.authorize method.

The request:

```
const request = {
         url: 'https://api-domain.com',
         method: 'POST',
         body: {
           someData: '1234',
         },
      };

const authHeader = Oauth1Helper.getAuthHeaderForRequest(request);

axios
  .post(request.url, request.body, {headers: authHeader})
  .then(res => {
     console.log(res);
  })
  .catch(err => {
     console.log(err);
  });
```

I hope it works!

Answer (score -1):

```
Simply we can pass oauth without library. as follows below.



var options = {
  'method': 'GET',
  'url': 'xxxx',
  'oauth': {
    consumer_key: CONSUMERKEY,
    consumer_secret: CONSUMERSECRET,
    token: TOKENKEY,
    token_secret: TOKENSECRET
  },
  'headers': {},
}

request(options, function (error, response) {
  if (error) console.log(error);
  console.log('response', response.body)
});
```