# node.js oauth-1.0a working for Twitter API v1.1 but not for v2

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter, twitter-oauth, oauth-1.0a

I've [found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60582493/2002514) this function to generate oauth-1.0a header:

```js
// auth.js

const crypto = require("crypto");
const OAuth1a = require("oauth-1.0a");

function auth(request) {
  const oauth = new OAuth1a({
    consumer: {
      key: process.env.TWITTER_API_KEY,
      secret: process.env.TWITTER_API_SECRET_KEY,
    },
    signature_method: "HMAC-SHA1",
    hash_function(baseString, key) {
      return crypto.createHmac("sha1", key).update(baseString).digest("base64");
    },
  });

  const authorization = oauth.authorize(request, {
    key: process.env.TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN,
    secret: process.env.TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET,
  });

  return oauth.toHeader(authorization).Authorization;
}

module.exports = auth;
```

It works fine if I try it with Twitter API v1.1:

```js
// v1.js

require("dotenv").config();
const axios = require("axios");
const auth = require("./auth");

const url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/favorites/create.json";
const method = "POST";
const params = new URLSearchParams({
  id: "1397568983931392004",
});

axios
  .post(url, undefined, {
    params,
    headers: {
      authorization: auth({
        method,
        url: `${url}?${params}`,
      }),
    },
  })
  .then((data) => {
    return console.log(data);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    if (err.response) {
      return console.log(err.response);
    }
    console.log(err);
  });
```

But if I try it with Twitter API v2:

```js
// v2.js

require("dotenv").config();
const axios = require("axios");
const auth = require("./auth");

const url = `https://api.twitter.com/2/users/${process.env.TWITTER_USER_ID}/likes`;
const method = "POST";
const data = {
  tweet_id: "1397568983931392004",
};

axios
  .post(url, data, {
    headers: {
      authorization: auth({
        method,
        url,
        data,
      }),
    },
  })
  .then((data) => {
    return console.log(data);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    if (err.response) {
      return console.log(err.response);
    }
    console.log(err);
  });
```

it fails with:

```
{
  title: 'Unauthorized',
  type: 'about:blank',
  status: 401,
  detail: 'Unauthorized'
}
```

I tried encoding the body of the request as suggested [here](https://github.com/draftbit/twitter-lite/blob/cc5c134c472436e39014c604c3b797146e928f61/twitter.js#L36), but get the same error:

```js
require("dotenv").config();
const axios = require("axios");
const auth = require("./auth");
const querystring = require("querystring");

const url = `https://api.twitter.com/2/users/${process.env.TWITTER_USER_ID}/likes`;
const method = "POST";
const data = percentEncode(
  querystring.stringify({
    tweet_id: "1397568983931392004",
  })
);

function percentEncode(string) {
  return string
    .replace(/!/g, "%21")
    .replace(/\*/g, "%2A")
    .replace(/'/g, "%27")
    .replace(/\(/g, "%28")
    .replace(/\)/g, "%29");
}

axios
  .post(url, data, {
    headers: {
      "content-type": "application/json",
      authorization: auth({
        method,
        url,
        data,
      }),
    },
  })
  .then((data) => {
    return console.log(data);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    if (err.response) {
      return console.log(err.response);
    }
    console.log(err);
  });
```

If tested with Postman, both endpoints (1.1 and 2) work fine with the same credentials.

Any ideas on what am I doing wrong while using v2 or how to get it working with Twitter API v2?

I suspect it's something related with the body of the request as that's the main diference between both requests, but haven't been able to make it work.

Comment: Is your app part of a project with access to API v2?

Comment: Yes it is, I have tested with postman and works, both V1.1 and V2, but this way it doesn't and want to figure it out.

Comment: @MauricioRobayo I am facing similar problem can someone please let me know how can I resolve it? Question link: https://twittercommunity.com/t/how-to-use-twitter-v2-apis/163669

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figure it out, the body of the request should not be included while generating the authorization header:

```js
require("dotenv").config();
const axios = require("axios");
const auth = require("./auth");

const url = `https://api.twitter.com/2/users/${process.env.TWITTER_USER_ID}/likes`;
const method = "POST";
const data = {
  tweet_id: "1397568983931392004",
};

axios
  .post(url, data, {
    headers: {
      authorization: auth({
        method,
        url,
      }),
    },
  })
  .then((data) => {
    return console.log(data);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    if (err.response) {
      return console.log(err.response);
    }
    console.log(err);
  });
```

Basically, when making a post request to Twitter API v1.1, the data should be encoded, should be used to generate the authorization header, and the post request should be sent as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

When making a post request to Twitter API v2, the data should not be encoded, should not be included while generating the authorization header, and must be sent as `application/json`.

Hope this becomes helpful to someone else.